# Is it possible to pre-compile (pre-build/pre-install) a Python C/C++ extension?

Tags: python, python-c-extension

There's a large Python project that I'm working on with several C/C++ extensions. Currently, every time I want to get the code running on a new machine, I have to download everything from the repository and then run `python setup.py install` several times, once for each extension... and that's assuming the computer has a C compiler installed--if it doesn't, that's another extra step or two.

Is there any way that I could pre-compile all of the C extensions so that when I download the repository to a new machine, everything works right out of the box without having to separately install all of these sub-components? I understand that this may not work well (or at all?) across different platforms, but let's say I pre-compiled things on a 64-bit Windows 8 machine and wanted to install it on another 64-bit Windows 8 machine--is that possible? If so, how would I go about doing it?

Comment: [pip wheel](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_wheel.html) might do what you want...though I've not used it myself

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. You are asking about [Creating Built Distributions](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/builtdist.html).

You can create such a built distribution like:

```
python setup.py bdist
```

You can even choose between different formats like:

```
python setup.py bdist --format=wininst
```

- `zip` zip file (.zip) [default]
- `wininst` self-extracting ZIP file for Windows
- `msi` Microsoft Installer

All this you can do with the standard `distutils` module.

If you would like to use a more modern *approach* and use `setuptools`, it is possible to build [Platform Wheels](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing.html#platform-wheels) for Windows:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

A last thing you could do is creating a `setup.py` file for all your extensions together. Even if you are *only* installing a source distribution, it would be much less work for you to do. With a build distribution it would be only one step to perform.